# Label disappearing after attributting it a parent

Tags: c#, winforms, parent

I have a Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Project. I have 2 picture boxes and I want to have 2 transparent labels over them to attribute an onclick event.

```
label1.Parent = pictureBox1;
label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
label2.Parent = pictureBox2;
label2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;`
```

The problem is that the first label works fine, becomes transparent and can be clicked, but the second one disappears when I give it a new parent.

Comment: Did you also adapt the Location from realtive to the old to to the new Parent? (You can use the various ScreentoPoint and back functions to calculate the exatct same position if you want to..)

Comment: I didnt. So you're saying that that label is somewhere else, hidden? xD I will try

Comment: somewhere else? yes. Hidden? no. Just moved out of sight, over the pbox boundaries.. Use the `MoveTo` function in the link if you want to keep the visible position! If you want to set the position otherwise, do so, e.g. `label2.Location = new Point(12,34)`